# How to make it Secure?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, permissions, security, wallet

I am building a website ( a platform ) which will have people communicate between each other and there is bound to be money transactions.

The amount of money in each customers account will be kept in Database , This can be redeemed by the customer at any time ( ie: the website is liable to pay back whatever is the balance amount shown in the database )

Required Details:
Database used : Mongodb

How do i keep my database and the transactions secure ?
Is there a problem with storing the account balance in database?
Are there better and secure methods to store money in database
Are there any concerns I should be worried about ?
Are the any steps precautions to be implemented?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145043/how-to-move-money-with-mongodb

Comment: Hmm... I hate to rain on your parade, but if you're dealing with people's money (as opposed to, say, points in a video game tournament or other stuff that "doesn't really matter"), then I would say, "Fine, fire ahead, and when your system falls flat on its face, then you can get back to us", but I think that, from the tone of your question, you should start off with a site that tracks something other than money - are you taking/storing credit card details? This is a big leap into the unknown and I would counsel you to get v. strong legal and technical  advice before doing so!

Comment: And, for your database use PostgreSQL, or if you want to put down serious cash, then go for Oracle, IBM, MS SQL Server or Informix or Sybase - they (all?) have trial editions with which you can start!

Comment: https://www.infoq.com/news/2014/04/bitcoin-banking-mongodb

Answer (score 3):

If you intend to transfer money from one user's account to another user's account you want to make absolutely sure that the amounts all balance out and nothing gets lost anywhere, even on a system failure. Mongo does not offer this guarantee since it does not support multi-record transactions. You will have to include additional application programing to provide this guarantee.

If money is involved then there will be audit considerations. Ask the authorities in your jurisdiction what their requirements are. Ensure you build these into the system from the start. Anti money laundering is a big thing too. Make sure the system can comply with local regulations.

It will never be sufficient to store the balance alone. You should have a complete transaction history of debits and credits for whatever duration your regulator requires - typically seven years. Double entry book-keeping principles   will be applicable.

Never, ever use floating point for anything. Know where all the rounding errors end up.

For security you will need multiple levels of prevention, detection and remediation. No software is perfect. All software has bugs, or relies on software (OS, DBMS, comms) that has bugs. These bugs *will* be exploited. Isolate each part of the application from others as much as possible. Grant minimum rights to run-time credentials. Make sure the lawyers agree the end-user terms and conditions. Good luck.

Comment: I beg to differ. It is a question of modeling. Document the individual transaction (`{from:“A“, to:“B“, amount:“42“}`), use aggregations to calculate the balance and Bob's your Uncle. Plus, you have a transaction log.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg As I said - "additional application programing."

Comment: Well, it seems like I misunderstood that part. The way I see it, data modelling is the key part here. Wether that is part of "additional application programming" or not is a matter of taste, I guess.